Is htmx 2.0 usable within a shadowrootmode?
In this example, only the second button works. Is it possible to make the first one work too?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>test htmx with shadowdom</title>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@2.0.0"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <template shadowrootmode="open">
                <header>Header</header>
                <main>
                    <button hx-post="/clicked" hx-swap="outerHTML">
                        doesn't work
                    </button>

                    <slot name="content1">
                        Loading...
                    </slot>
                </main>
                <footer>Footer</footer>
            </template>

            <div slot="content1">
                <button hx-post="/clicked" hx-swap="outerHTML">
                    works
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

My goal is to do something like Streaming HTML out of order without JavaScript.
I would like to avoid sse since I would prefer that the server start processing the data needed for "content1" right away and stream it when ready.
